# Inverse limit of small categories

Tags: category-theory

It is well known that category $\mathcal{Cat}$ of small categories has all small limits and colimits. In particular it has all iverse limits.

I am wondering if there is an explicit constraction of an inverse limit of an inverse system of small categories  $$\mathcal C_1\leftarrow\mathcal C_2\leftarrow\cdots $$ like for sets or topological spaces.

I think that it could be a category where objects would be the elements of the limit of this inverse system considered as limit in sets. Functors would be considered as the functions in this case (we forget about the morphisms). And the morphisms between two threads $(A_1,A_2,\ldots)$ and $(B_1,B_2,\ldots)$ would be $(f_1,f_2,\ldots)$ where $f_i:A_i\to B_i$ is a morphism in $\mathcal C_i$ for each $i\in\mathbb N_{+}$.

Am I right?

Comment: Limits in $\mathbf{Cat}$ are constructed in the obvious way. This is because the functors $\operatorname{ob}, \operatorname{mor} : \mathbf{Cat} \to \mathbf{Set}$ are representable.

Comment: @ZhenLin: This is an answer.